# Which JAX-B annotated class implements following both representations?

Tags: java, json, xml, jaxb, jackson

Which JAX-B annotated class implements following both representations 
(with Jackson's [JacksonJaxbJsonProvider](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider/javadoc/2.0.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/jaxrs/json/JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.html))?

JSON:

```
{"propertyList": [ 
     {"key": "aKey", "value": "someValue"}, 
     {"key": "anotherKey", "value": "someOtherValue"}
]}
```

XML:

```
 <root>
    <propertyList>
        <property>
            <key>aKey</key>
            <value>someValue</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <key>anotherKey</key>
            <value>someOtherValue</value>
        </property>
   </propertyList>
</root>
```

Following classes implement JSON:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElement
    private List<Property> propertyList;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Property {

    @XmlElement
    private String key;

    @XmlElement
    private String value;
}
```

Following class implements XML:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root{

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="propertyList")
    @XmlElement(name="property")
    private List<Property> propertyList;
}
```

Exists an implementation for both representations? Or is there a way to use the @XmlElementWrapper with JSON?

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with the [JsonProperty](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root{

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="propertyList")
    @XmlElement(name="property")
    @JsonProperty("propertyList")
    private List<Property> propertyList;
}
```